# Salesforce: Security Review- Second Organization

Tags: security-review

A quick question on the security review process, I have everything set up and running on the original developer organization, the publisher portion of it is good. I have no issues outstanding with the package uploaded, except one thing. I'm getting flagged for my second testing organization not having the right version running, went through and double checked I had it after some running around I got the perfect version installed for both testing/review organizations. On my second organization though I cant seem to get the app running properly. There a step Im missing? Im litterally glossing over at the more than numerous pdf's. Anyone have an idea or breadbrumb to set me in the right direction?

Regards. J.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a packaging issue and not a Security Review issue. You can file a developer support case to make sure your package works as intended when installed in a fresh DE org.